# PC did a chkdsk scan on startup without me scheduling it

Tags: bios, uefi, chkdsk

so, my pc did a chkdsk scan on startup without me even accessing cmd beforehand. by the way, before it did the scan i was in the UEFI but I didnt change anything, I just looked at the settings and left with discarding all changes (just in case I changed something) should i be worried?

Comment: UEFI firmware/BIOS settings have nothing to do with filesystems, as they're accessed before the UEFI firmware/BIOS hands off to the bootloader, and it's only after the OS bootloader loads that filesystems are mounted.

Answer (score 1):

I normally run chkdsk once a month to check for issues. It normally gets invoked by a non-clean shutdown. i.e. powering off without shutting down. I wouldn't worry too much about it unless it happens every time you switch on. Sometimes windows crashes on shutdown, causing the machine to reboot instead.